# Re-building sets - paid services?

Tags: piece-information, instructions, disassembly, organisation, glue

My son has A LOT of LEGO sets, which have sadly broken down into many, many millions of pieces. Does anyone know of any paid services that might help re-build his sets.

I know this sounds like it goes against the principles of LEGO, but really it's just too daunting, and he's lost interest because of it.

Answer (score 4):

With “services”, do you mean someone who would come out to your house and rebuild the sets for you? As intriguing as that sounds, I do not believe something like that exists. Your best bet is to grab an instruction manual and start rebuilding from the pieces. Once you have a few sets built this way, it’ll become easier to rebuild the remaining sets. For sets that you know he has but you cannot find a manual, go to lego.com to download the instructions. Then, once it’s down to a few unknown sets, make pictures of the unusual pieces and post them here - we can help you identify the set(s).

Comment: Adding to this, OP could even invite some friends over to help with the process. Many kids and adults are really neat, organized, or even OCD, and they love sorting and organizing LEGO pieces. Put on some soft background music and it can be an almost therapeutic experience.

Answer (score 2):

You're correct that it's absurd; services to build your Legos for you do not exist to my knowledge.

I would try taking an evening and organizing the parts that you have. Make it a parent-son thing - order a pizza, put on a movie, spread out everything you have on the floor and start separating the parts into groups. My suggestion: First group by general type (plates, bricks, hinges, etc), then by color.

Then comes the fun part: rebuilding. If you remember any of the sets that you have, you can download building instructions from the Lego website [here](https://www.lego.com/en-us/service/buildinginstructions). Once you're done separating by color/type it should be trivial to find the parts you need for any particular set.

Or just eschew this entire process altogether and encourage him to build something entirely from his imagination. Either way, your encouragement and/or involvement is a good thing.

Comment: I would argue that sorting by type first is better than colour in you are working to instructions. For example in a pile of black pieces it is hard to find the exact brick you need, but in a pile of 2x2 bricks it is easy to find the black one.

Comment: This is the best answer so far, I think. I can be a lot of fun to spread the instructions out in front of you and start calling out "2 4-length black beams! 1 6 length black axle!" (or whatever nomenclature you want to use -- "red square thingy" is also acceptable) and go hunting for them. At least, that's what I do with my daughter. We both like coming up with the precise Lego nomenclature for the pieces. Or maybe _I_ do and she goes along with that.

Comment: @Craig I agree with your suggestion and have edited the post accordingly.

Comment: A very important aspect of building with LEGO is finding the parts! It builds character: patience, fine motor skills, visual acuity, spatial relations, and the appreciation for randomly associating parts. Over time it will make you a better builder, as your LEGO "vocabulary" will get much better. You learn what parts look like rotated & upside down, their sizes, especially in relation to each other. And you learn your inventory.